# 2 step filtration in Mysql+PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql VIEW that users with different privileges has access to it within a web page generated with PHP.

If somehow possible, I want to make a primary filtration before put it into user access according to his/her privileges. Every salesman should have access only to its own customers. So our VIEW should be filtered primarily for this condition when the web page is created. Then user should have access to this already filtered view for further interrogations within the view.

What kind of logic or technique should I put into application to simplify this process

Comment: Unless each of your application users has a mysql user as wel, you canot do this in a mysql view, since the filter value will depend on the application level user id. You need to use a plain old select query with parameters.

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE username = 'my username'

Comment: Better to filter your view with some value, like salesman username or something like this.